# Custom function in testcafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

So, i am trying to create a custom function that will allow me to check if a field contains a number or a text, but for further test i will need to check more complex stuff, like if the sum of some table equals something, etc. 
I can't find examples of custom functions for example:

```js
function isNumber(n) {
  let a = parseInt(n);
  if (a > 0 || a < 0) {
    return true
  } 
  return false
}
test('Test example', async t => {
  await t
      .expect(isNumber(Selector('#thisNum').innerText)).ok('This is a number' );
    
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The assertion message will only be displayed [when the assertion fails](http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/assertions/assertion-api.html#ok) (refer to the message parameter). For example,

```
await t
  .expect(failingValue).ok('failingValue is not a number');
```

Would display something like the following on a failed test:

```
1) AssertionError: failingValue is not a number: expected false to be truthy
```

Therefore, I'd never expect to see the "This is a number" message displayed.

As for the function, I've experienced a couple of instances where the promise wasn't resolved yet, so try awaiting the number selector:

```
await t
  .expect(isNumber(await Selector('#thisNum').innerText)).ok('This is a number');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Alex!  At the end i decided to use cypress.js but your solution seems to work as a charm